# What properties will rest skip in Object Destructuring?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, frontend, babeljs

I am using rest parameter to do some operations, but got some properties disappeared in result.

The data format of `this.props` looks like this:

````
```
this.props = {
  data: [{...}, ...],
  ...
}
```
````

And I tried to rest it in this way:

````
```
let {showWaveAnimation, ...otherProps} = this.props;

console.log('data' in otherProps); // false
console.log('data' in this.props); //true
```
````

Why would 'data' property lost after I tried rest operation?

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters#Difference_between_rest_parameters_and_the_arguments_object), I found the description:

> rest parameters are only the ones that haven't been given a separate name (i.e. formally defined in function expression), while the arguments object contains all arguments passed to the function;

What does `separate name` here means? Is it means properties that extends from its prototype would not be rest? But after I tried the following statements, I got the same result, I am confusing.

````
```
class Parent {
    constructor() {
        this.props = {
            data: '123',
        };
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.props.childProp = 'test';

        let {test, ...otherProps} = this.props;
        console.log('data' in this.props, 'data' in otherProps);
        // true true
    }
}

new Child();
```
````

The former code behaviors abnormal after Babel's transpiling, could it be Babel's plugin problem?

ADD: I found this concept may be more precise in describing my `rest` operations. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Rest_in_Object_Destructuring

Comment: @Rajesh Hi, I am using it in `Object`, so there's no need to keep it indexed as array? And the operation I wrote in `Child` class can work normally.

Comment: Not to be pedantic here, but it seems you're actually asking about the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). It uses the same syntax, but has a subtle, but key, difference in use.

Comment: @DrewReese I think I am looking for the right method for rest in object destructuring actually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out why 'data' disappeared in my rest result, it's the `enumerable` property of 'data' field!

Once, the property is set as `enumerable: false`, we can't get it with the operation of rest in object destructuring.

According to MDN

> The Rest/Spread Properties for ECMAScript proposal (stage 3) adds the rest syntax to destructuring. Rest properties collect the remaining own enumerable property keys that are not already picked off by the destructuring pattern.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Rest_in_Object_Destructuring

I think this example can explain my ideas more precisely:

```js
const person = {  
  name: 'Dave',
  surname: 'Bowman'
};

Object.defineProperty(person, 'age', {  
  enumerable: false, // Make the property non-enumerable
  value: 25
});
console.log(person['age']); // => 25

const clone = {  
  ...person
};
console.log(clone); // => { name: 'Dave', surname: 'Bowman' }
```

Comment: Are you changing/ setting `enumerable: false`  for data? Its not visible in question

Comment: @Rajesh Actually, it's `false` exactly, but it's defined by the framework, so I didn't notice it in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

The rest parameter allows you to get all the remaining attributes not already selected by identifier preceding it in the assignment.

- Let's take a simple example:

```js
const obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3
}

const { a, ...rest } = obj;

console.log(a);
console.log(rest);
```

Above `obj` has a property named `a` so it is destructured from `obj` and assigned to the variable `a`, then all other properties are assigned in an object to `rest`.

- However, what you have is more like:

```js
const obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3
}

const { d, ...rest } = obj;

console.log(d);
console.log(rest);
```

Here `obj` doesn't have a property named `d`. So it is destructured from `obj` as `undefined` and assgined to the variable `a`. Then all other properties not already assigned, i.e. `a`, `b` and `c` are given to `rest`.

In your code `otherProps` has the same properties as `this.props`, because object `this.props` doesn't have a property named `test`. **In other words, in order to destructure an object you have to know its structure.**

Comment: This doesn't answer this: `console.log('data' in otherProps); // false`

Comment: @Rajesh It's actually the setting of enumerable, I add an example in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

> > rest parameters are only the ones that haven't been given a separate name (i.e. formally defined in function expression), while the arguments object contains all arguments passed to the function;
>
> What does separate name here means? Is it means properties that extends from its prototype would not be rest? But after I tried the following statements, I got the same result, I am confusing.

Given a function definition `function foo(a, b, ...c) {}`, arguments `a`, and `b` are the named parameters, whereas the rest of the passed arguments are spread into the last variable `c`.  Now, `c` *is* a named variable, but any parameters passed from the third on will just be accessible in `c`, i.e. `c[0]`.

Now, your console.log error is stemming from your use of the [`in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) operator.  You defined an object `const foo = {'data': 'bar'}`. `'data' in foo` is true, but `'blarg' in foo` is false since foo doesn't contain a key/property named 'blarg'.

You're actually using the spread operator to destructure your props object into several named variables.

```js
const object = {
  data: 'foo',
  other: 'bar',
  moreData: [1,2,3],
};

// Example usage of the spread operator
const { data, ...allTheRest} = object;  // data is destructured, other and moreData into allTheRest

console.log(data);
console.log(allTheRest);

// in operator
console.log('data' in object); // true
console.log('data' in allTheRest); // false
console.log('moreData' in allTheRest); // true
```

```js
// This is an example of the rest operator
const foo = (...allTheArgs) => {
  allTheArgs.forEach(e => console.log(e));
}

foo(1,2,3); // all the args are collected into a single array variable in the function
```

```js
const bar = (a, b, ...c) => {
  console.log(`a: ${a}`);
  console.log(`b: ${b}`);
  console.log(`c: ${c}`);
};

bar('this is first param', 42, 'foo', 'bar', '1', 2, 'stackoverflow');
```

Comment: Actually I found it's because the 'data' property in my object is not enumerable, but thanks for replying! What I am confused about is can I call `a` and `b` in your code been given a **seperate name**?

Comment: I added a third example to show how to use `a`, and `b`.  Hopefully it answers your question.